# unable to open localhost on Debian

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, webrick

I've started to learn Ruby on rails but I can't open `localhost:3000`, `0.0.0.0:3000` and `127.0.0.1:3000` in my Chrome browser.

```
=> Booting WEBrick
=> Rails 4.0.4 application starting in development on http://0.0.0.0:3000
=> Run `rails server -h` for more startup options
=> Ctrl-C to shutdown server
[2014-03-31 14:40:49] INFO  WEBrick 1.3.1
[2014-03-31 14:40:49] INFO  ruby 2.1.0 (2013-12-25) [x86_64-linux]
[2014-03-31 14:40:49] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=23204 port=3000
```

/etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   Hexbook.Dlink   Hexbook

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     localhost ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
127.0.0.1 smxi.org
http://smxi.org smxi.org
209.197.72.47 smxi.org
```

in browser error ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT

and curl:

```
root@Hexbook:/home/hexxy# curl 127.0.0.1:3000
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

problem solved:

```
ifconfig lo 127.0.0.1 up
```

Comment: what are you seeing there ?

Comment: Can you also tell us the output of your /etc/hosts file?

Comment: When you issue something like `curl 127.0.0.1:3000` do you see `Connection refused` ?

Comment: In browser ERR_INVALID_ARGUMENT
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host

Comment: is your rails server on the same machine as your browser?

Comment: I'm getting this same crap, Hexxy. I loath the linux community, so freaking sharded and useless.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely some other application is using that port.

You can try to find out which one it is, or you can try to use another port, usually via some -p or a similar switch.

Comment: I tried to use 3001, 3008, 8808
the same error in browser